# Signification de « est sans doute pour [...] »

Tags: expressions

J'ai lu dans un article la phrase suivante:

> La culture universelle « moderne » qui connaît aujourd’hui une crise
>   problématique, dominée par la loi du marché et dépouillée de toute éthique, **est sans doute pour beaucoup quant à la redécouverte** des diversités culturelles.

Je ne comprend pas, je me demande: « est sans doute quoi? ».

Comment: La culture universelle « moderne » qui connaît aujourd’hui une crise problématique ... est sans doute pour beaucoup [quant à ->] *dans* la redécouverte des diversités culturelles.-- Reformulée : la redécouverte des diversités culturelles est en grande partie due à la crise problématique (ontologique) de la culture universelle.

Answer (score 2):

La phrase indiquée est **incorrecte**: on n'utilise pas *pour beaucoup quant à* , mais *pour beaucoup dans*

**est pour beaucoup dans :  est la principale cause/origine/explication de**

*pour beaucoup dans* seul (sans verbe être) signifie *principalement*, *essentiellement* *dans*:

> La solution réside/se trouve **pour beaucoup** dans l'emploi de cette
>   technologie.

On trouve *pour beaucoup* seul, comme adverbe, qui remplace : beaucoup de:

> Ils jouent **pour beaucoup** au football = **beaucoup d**'eux jouent au
>   football.

Answer (score 2):

À mon avis, on a simplement oublié le ***y*** dans une locution du type [*y être pour quelque chose*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/y/82937/locution), c'est-à-dire *avoir une part de responsabilité, [...] dans quelque chose* (Larousse), donc ici une grande part de responsabilité (beaucoup) mais on y avait intercalé un *sans doute* pour marquer le propos. On peut reprendre simplement le cœur de la phrase (avec l'apport des autres réponses pour *dans*) :

> La culture universelle « moderne » **y** est pour beaucoup *dans* la
>   redécouverte des diversités culturelles.

Dans la phrase en question, on y a inséré une relative (*qui*...) et des attributs (*dominée*... *dépouillée*) pour décrire la culture universelle « moderne » mais on a mal bouclé le tout. Il s'agit ici d'une construction basée sur une locution (normalement davantage figée), et l'analyse du pronom est parfois ardue (comparer *n'y pouvoir rien*), mais le pronom (y) réfère vraisemblablement à la *redécouverte des diversités culturelles* ; *à cela* peut être un substitut utile pour le décortiquer...

Comment: Le pronom "y" remplaçant "dans la redécouverte ...", mettre les deux est redondant, comme: j'y suis dans la ville.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Il s'agit de _J'y suis pour quelque chose_ et de _Elle y est pour beaucoup dans la redécouverte_. Le pronom fait partie de l'expression et il n'y a aucune redondance ici.

Comment: La bonne réponse est qu'il y aune erreur, il manque effectivement le Y pour que ça soit français ;)

Answer (score 1):

"être pour beaucoup dans"

peut se reformuler comme

"avoir beaucoup contribué à"

"avoir joué un grand rôle dans"